# A Drink and a Game

Tags: board-games, acrostic

I saw this text chain on my friend's phone.  **What was ordered to drink?**
To answer, you'll need to figure out the name of the game they were playing. I'm sure you've heard of it. There are a few subtle hints scattered throughout.

> -Nick! How are the kids? I heard Jimmy caught the flu. What about Janet?
> -*Sick as Jimmy. U?*
> -Lisa's better now. We're going out to Al's tonight. Has a good m. scene.
> -*M. scene?*
> -By that, I meant music scene.
> -*A q… can we go?*
> -Heh, you and Trish? Dunno, it's pretty exclusive. What are your credentials? 
> -*V.P., B.A.*
> -Boy, that should work. We're placing a food order. What would you like?
> -*Us? Wings.*
> -Heard they are good there. How ‘bout to drink?
> -*????!*
> -I'm on it. See you at 4.
> -4? Sorry… we'll be a few hours late. In the middle of a board game right now.

Comment: Should the last message be italicized?

Comment: @msh210 nope it's regular

Comment: I was thinking it was a card game of Gin Rummy, until I read it was a board game.